# Java JIT compilation can optimize a method when it returns always the same value?

Tags: java, performance, jit

In my Java application I have some methods that always return the same thing. So, Is JIT able to detect these methods and optimize the performance (clone the result instead of calculate it or other way) ?

Example of candidate method for the optimisation :

```
private List<String> get() {
    return Arrays.asList(Operation.values()).stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In my point of view it is not possible, but I am no sure.

Comment: It is possible, but very unlikely. It is also likely unnecessary, unless you call that `get()` method inside a tight loop.

Comment: Only way you can find this out is run the code using -Djava.compiler=NONE and without using the option in loop several times and compare the timing

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab I don’t know whether that ancient system property has any effect, but anyway, disabling all optimizations doesn’t help in finding out whether a particular optimization exists.

Comment: Particular optimizations are implementation specific. In case of HotSpot, I don’t think that there is a “clone the result” like feature, but that doesn’t mean that a maximally optimized version of this operation is too far away from what the “clone the result” code had to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) (CSE) is a well-known compiler optimization to avoid recalculation of identical expressions. In general, JVM is capable of such optimization.

But this is not your case. The given `get()` method does **not** return the same thing.

First of all, assuming that `Operation` is enum type, `Operation.values()` returns new array each time. It must return a new object to protect the original array from modification.

`Collectors.toList()` in its current implementation also returns a new `ArrayList` each time. JVM cannot do anything about this allocation since the returned object is visible outside.

Comment: Actually, `Operation.values()` *could* return the shared array, when the JVM could prove that it doesn't get modified in the method, that its identity doesn't matter and that it doesn't escape (and maybe more such conditions?). However, I'd bet that such an optimization is not implemented.

Comment: @maaartinus or implement copy-on-write arrays. In theory…

Comment: @Holger Interesting idea. Problems: 1. It may cost some performance even when unused. 2. Something like `Whatever w1 = leak(array); Whatever w2 = leak(array); assertSame(w1.getArray(), w2.getArray())` would require copying before calling first `leak` or sharing of the copies.

Comment: @maaartinus it would work best, if object header and actual array data were separated, so a new array object with distinct identity could be created to be formally correct, but without copying the array data, which usually is the more (if not only) expensive thing.